# How to configure the top level view's autoresizingmask in an autolayout enabled xib?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib, autoresize

I have this xib that has autolayout enabled, there's only one view (let's call it viewA) in it. I added this view as a subview to another view (let's call it viewB). ViewB doesn't use autolayout, and I set viewA's frame programmatically.

The problem is, when viewB's frame changes, viewA's frame changes accordingly. I realized that I need to configure viewA's autoresizingmask, but can't find where to change it in xib. Thanks a lot!

Comment: set autoresizingmask programmatically, you can't set it in the xib

Comment: Thanks @jinhualiao, I decided to give up. Thanks for saving my time :)

Comment: You can achieve this using auto-layout also. just give proper constraint & if needed create outlet of constraints & change its size through constraints

Comment: @swapnalipatil for what I can see, I can't add constraint to the top level view in xib...